# How to track Git commits with multiple users, a common login and a shared working directory?

Tags: git

Here's the scenario: a Windows PC is running test software automating hardware tests. The code to control the tests is managed in a Git repository. There is a single, common login with a password known by all the test operators.

How do I set it up so that when a user wants to do a commit, it asks them for their username and email, or they can supply it per-commit? We need to track which individual made the change. Sometimes hot-changes are necessary and we want to make sure that the state of all files that affect the test is preserved in the repository.

Please do not recommend fundamental configuration changes or that each user work out of a separate directory and then do merges - those workflows will not accommodate the needs of the test. The common login is because the process of switching between users would close the software running the test and could lead to damage or failed tests. If there is no solution for this, we will be forced to revert to SVN... and no one wants that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the author name and email every time you run `git commit`, like this:

```
git -c user.name='Alex Court' -c user.email=alex@example.com commit
```

You may want to ensure your `.gitconfig` file does not have any name or email configured, so that git will not use those if someone forgets.  Or you may want to write a wrapper script which prompts the user in a more interactive way.

Answer (score 1):

@JohnZwinck's answer works, another option with different minor inconveniences is to have people do e.g.

```
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='John Kugelman' GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=johnk@example.com
```

and you could set up a shell function named `hi,im` in the login profile to set those from a list, something like (fingers-to-textbox):

```
hi,im() { match=`grep "$*"` ~/namelist
        local nmatch=`printf %s "$match"|wc -l`
        test $nmatch = 1 \
        || { echo "$match"; echo need one match for \"$*\" in ~/namelist; exit; }
        eval $match
}
```

with `~/namelist` containing exports as above. If you're the only `johnk` you could just `hi,im johnk` when starting your runs. Include `$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` in your prompt string, simplest would be `export PS1='$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME\$ '` to include the current person's name as a reminder at every prompt.

Then if the prompt's got your name in it you can operate as usual, otherwise `hi,im jthill`